# Web Client for Raspbian MiniDLNA

Tags: raspbian, media-server

I installed and set up MiniDLNA on my Pi/Raspbian and it is working absolutely fine.

However, I thought of a web client for it so that I can run it on the Pi and play the media from anywhere with a browser. Is there something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I use a [mpd (music player daemon)](http://www.musicpd.org) on my pi and an mpc on the client side(macbook, phone and tablet). You also can install a web-based client (mpc) like rompr and use it from any browser.
I think this is the best solution to listen music, because there are a lot of different clients for different os. You also can connect with more than one client to the server (mpd) - very practical for parties, if the  guests complain about the music, you can submit a tablet around and everyone can add his music to a playlist.

Comment: Just a link to rompr here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/rompr/ :D

Answer (score 0):

I am using Logitech Media Server (formerly SqueezePlug server) as a streaming server at my home. At my work laptop squeezeplug client installed. I believe that it's a better solution than DLNA. (I'm using DLNA to stream video to my TV by the way.)

There is a installation document for Logitech Media Server: http://allthingspi.webspace.virginmedia.com/lms.php

Also;

There are many solutions work as 'streaming server' to use on RPi.

http://www.raspyfi.com/
http://www.pimusicbox.com/
http://www.fomori.org/cherrymusic/index.html